# Update UI when using stringWithContentsofurl

Tags: iphone, string, user-interface, download

I am using stringWithcontentsofurl to download some strings from my web server to the App, but i would like to update the UI to show A loader of some kind. I am downloading a number of strings (it can be sometimes as much as 100) so it would be neat for the user to show something so they know the App isn't crashing, because now the UI is stuck, i can't show A UILoader or something like that. Is there an option to do so? Or maybe A alternative to stringWithcontentsofurl where this is possible?

greets,
Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic case for "Lazy Loading". See Apple's example code:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

It should be easy to substitute "strings" for "images" as you read that code.

You want to display a placeholder in the label like "(fetching information)" or similar and then load the information in the background, either threading the fetches yourself (asynchronous fetching) or using a library like ASIHTTPRequest that handles all the asynchronous nuts and bolts for you, calling a delegate method once the fetch has completed.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It loads stuff in background. If updating the UI later (in asyncload), be sure to do that on main thread.

```
-(void)loadappdetails:(NSString*)appid {
    NSString* searchurl = [@"https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=" stringByAppendingString:appid];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(asyncload:) withObject:searchurl];

}
-(void)asyncload:(NSString*)searchurl {
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:searchurl];
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSString* str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
    NSLog(@"str: %@", str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `stringWithContentsOfURL` is a synchronous method, meaning it will block your thread and you will not receive any callbacks while it is running. This is also bad for user experience.

The alternative would be to use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003755) to manually setup your own request, and tap into the delegate methods of your connection to display some sort of progress bar. Specifically, you'll want to use `connection:didReceiveData:` and `connectionDidFinishLoading:`

Once all the data has been received, use the following to get your string.

```
NSString *theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:yourData encoding:UTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I have found the method `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` but i do not really understand it, could you give an example?

Comment: That method is currently only available in `NSURLConnection` on Mac OS X 10.7. For iOS, you want to create a new `NSURLRequest`, then use the `connectionWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` method. Apple has a good example here - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Answer (score 0):

To make this method asynch it is possible and recommendable to use Grand Central Dispatch. If anyone is interested I will show the few lines of code to do that.