# How make update of my UILabel in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

i have my code for parsing:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://site.ch/parse.php"] 
                                          encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding 
                                             error:&error];
```

From this code i getting name track from url radio. 
Also i getting this to my label:

```
[labelName setStringValue:text];
```

Question: How to update my label? I want that my label to be updated after 5 sec  from URL. I used timer schedule..but after this my app became very slow...help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you just put the above code in viewDidLoad of a view controller or similar, you actually block the main thread (i.e, the UI thread), causing the app to be in-responsive for the amount of time it takes to retrieve the string from site.ch/parse.php. As suggested, you should download the string in the background. Also, modifying UI must be done on the main thread:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://site.ch/parse.php"] 
                                      encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding 
                                         error:&error];

    // checking if error == nil would be appropriate

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.labelName.text = text;
    });    
});
```

This sample (my apologies for any typos) downloads the text from site.ch/parse.php in the background and sets the label when finished. Also, [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004494/update-ui-when-using-stringwithcontentsofurl) it would be a good idea to display a placeholder text while download the real text.

Also, have a look at [performSelector:withObject:afterDelay](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you wish to do so.

Comment: i wanted to answer this question but after reading this answer there is nothing left to say +1

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use background thread or GCD thread to update your text continuously.

Comment: How its make? If its possible help me for this.

Comment: updating something in the UI in a background thread? Are you crazy?

Comment: after getting the data perform a selector on main thread after that that label will be updated

Comment: if we do as what you said @Suraj Gupta then main thread is required to wait until those threads finishes for clean exit, it can cause dead lock condition. which we dont want in our app

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use any background thread to get data from the url and after getting you data you can update the value of the label.By this there should be no effect on your app performance.